# Google Business Listing

Tags: marketing

What is meant by Google Local Business Listing? How it is useful for Promoting a site?

Answer (score 1):

Google business listing is a solution

Comment: If you're not spamming, where did you find "FerociousMedia.com" and how do you know their commercial site offers credible information? It looks like they've been spamming a bit http://www.quora.com/Tem-Abbigail and http://www.librarything.com/groups/ferociousmediamilfor ...

Comment: @danlefree: Definitely spam. That link had absolutely no informational value. There was only 3 sentences of content on that page, and it was marketing copy for the company's services.

Comment: Oh, btw Abbie, kiss your Google adWords certification and Microsoft adExcellence accreditation goodbye...